# How to set VIM colorscheme based on directory?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I often switch between different apps would like each project to have it's own colorscheme so its easier to tell them apart.

I want to put something like the following in my .vimrc but I'm having trouble with the VIM scripting syntax.

```
# if I were to write it in Ruby
case current_path
when '/path/to/project'       then color textmate
when '/path/to/other_project' then color ir_black
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't want to mix different projects in a single instance of Vim (colorschemes can only be set globally, not for individual windows!), this is trivial to translate to Vimscript:

```
if getcwd() ==# '/path/to/project'
    colorscheme textmate
elseif getcwd() ==# '/path/to/other_project'
    colorscheme ir_black
endif
```

For an extensive configuration, I would probably use a Dictionary lookup in a loop instead, but I've kept this intentionally simple.

To handle subdirectories, use this for the comparison:

```
if stridx(getcwd(), '/path/to/project') == 0
```

You can also do regexp matching via `=~#` instead of `==#`.

---

Alternatively, there are a couple of *local vimrc* plugins, which allow you to apply project-specific settings to certain subdirectories. I use [localrc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393) for this.

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your localrc link. The localrc plugin can be found here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393

Answer (score 0):

For project settings, consider using the [project plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69): for each project, you could specify an `in.vim` file whose content gets executed every time you open a file of this project.

Setting a colorscheme there is trivially easy.

Using the project plugin also enables you to set up other project-dependent settings for each individual project:

> Other features include:
>    o Loading/Unloading all the files in a Project (\l, \L, \w, and \W)
>    o Grepping all the files in a Project (\g and \G)
>    o Running a user-specified script on a file (can be used 
>      to launch an external program on the file) (\1 through \9)
>    o Running a user-specified script on all the files in a Project 
>      (\f1-\f9 and \F1-\F9)
>    o Also works with the netrw plugin using directory 
>      names like `ftp://remotehost`
>                (Good for webpage maintenance.)
>    o Support for custom mappings for version control 
>      integration (example of perforce in the documentation).
>    o I also give an example in the documentation on how to 
>      set up a custom launcher based on extension. The 
>      example launches *.jpg files in a viewer. I have also set 
>      up viewers for PDF (acroread) and HTML files (mozilla) 
>      for my own use.