# changing VIM interface based on project

Tags: vim

Will be following something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842247/how-to-set-vim-colorscheme-based-on-direcory) to set vim setting based on the project.

My question is: what might be a good effect to greatly highlight/warn what project im in.

My preference would be to somehow surround my VIM screen with a red text border. Is something like that possible? That would really standout.  Less interested in colour scheme, since my brain might too easily ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

*When your brain ignores even totally different colorschemes, I'd stop coding, as you're bound to ignore vastly more subtle differences in the code, too.*

This depends greatly on your setup and personal preferences. My own preference is a `[projectname]` appended to the `'titlestring'`, but that may be way too subtle for you. Apart from that, Vim allows different colors (and font if you're using GVIM). Of course, you may be able to influence the window decoration through your window manager, using `system()` inside Vim to control that (or building that into an alias that launches Vim).